# Finding the smallest value $c$ such that $x^n < c(1+nx)$

Tags: inequality

Can we find the smallest value $c$ such that  $x^n < c(1+nx)$ for all positive real numbers $x$ and for all positive integers $n$, if the value exists?

I always thought quadratic functions always grow faster than linear functions ... but now I'm not sure, hence my question.

Comment: Welcome Math.SE! Take the [tour](http://math.stackexchange.com/tour) to get familiar with this site. Mathematical expressions and equations can be [formatted](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) using $LaTeX$ syntax. please share your thoughts and attempts towards the solution. If you receive useful answers, consider [accepting](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) one.

Comment: There is no $c$ such that $x^n<c(1+nx)$ for every positive $x$ and $n=2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

answer is no , there is no value of $c$ . to prove this consider function $$g(x)=x^n -c(1+nx)$$ 
now calculate $$\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty}g(x)=x^2.(x^{n-2}+\frac{c}{x}(\frac{1}{x}+n))$$
you will find for all $c$ this limit goes to $\infty$

Comment: Wait, I got the limit to be $\infty-\infty$ for all c > 0 and n > 0 which is indeterminate

Comment: @user347428 check the edit